# I use python socket module to simulate a pppoe server, but how to generate the ppp0 interface?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ppp, pppoe

I use python socket module to simulate a pppoe server, the server can receive ppp connection packet from client such as PADI/PADR/LCP Request... , however after the connection finished,there is no ppp0 interface on sever.
I wish the ppp0 interface can be up automatically after the ppp connection finished ,please help...

```py
import socket

def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x8863))

    interface ='eth0'

    server_socket.bind((interface, 0))

    while True:
        try:
            data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(4096)
            '''
            handle pppoe packets here and finish the pppoe connection
            '''

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    server_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My OS is ubuntu 18.04..

I expect that after the ppp connection between client and server finished, there should be a ppp0 interface on my server.

For example server IP is 20.20.20.1 and the client get IP 20.20.20.2 ,I wish the interface on server should be like:

```
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 20.20.20.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 20.20.20.2
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 194  bytes 14365 (14.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 175  bytes 13081 (13.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Anyone have some ideas? Thanks...

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you have tried

Comment: ok,I have add some code ...

Answer (score 0):

The OS handle Virtual interfaces.

According to OS you are using, you should read manuals about it.

For example in linux you can use networkd or ip command to make a new virtual interface.

You can use these commands:

```
ip link add name MYNEWINTERFACE type dummy
ifconfig MYNEWINTERFACE up
```

Check other options with:

```
man ip-link
```

Comment: I have try this method and it doesn't work，my OS is ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Answer edited, check plz.

Comment: I use ip link add can successful add a virtual interface,however it is not ppp protocol, I want generate a ppp protocol interface and it should be like 


'''ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 20.20.20.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 20.20.20.2
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 194  bytes 14365 (14.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 175  bytes 13081 (13.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
 '''

Comment: Did you check type parameter in ip link add?

Comment: yeah, ip-link do not support add type of ppp